# Evaluating Prime counting function using Riemann's R-function and zeros of Zeta function

Tags: number-theory

Prime counting function can be expressed as follows:
$\pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) \tag{1}$
where R(x) is Riemann's R-function and $\rho$-s are zeros of Riemann zeta function. I am able to evaluate R(x) for any x. I can also evaluate the sum over trivial zeros of zeta function, which converges rapidly. The problem I have is evaluating the sum over the non-trivial zeros. It seems to diverge. I always read somewhere that including more non-trivial zeros you get more accurate approximation of $\pi(x)$. But for me the best approximate is not using any zeros $\pi(x) \sim \operatorname{R}(x)$.

When I use no zeros $\pi(x) \sim \operatorname{R}(x)$ I get [blue line (see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA8dr.png).

When I use first pair of nontrivial zeros $\pi(x) \sim \operatorname{R}(x)-(\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_1})+\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_{-1}}))$ I get [yellow line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA8dr.png).

When I use first two pairs of nontrivial zeros $\pi(x) \sim \operatorname{R}(x)-(\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_1})+\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_{-1}})+\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_2})+\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_{-2}}))$ I get green line (same image).
(Red line is $\pi(x)$)

With more zeros it gets worse and worse, but the apposite should be true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The tips at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610359/if-these-two-expressions-for-calculating-the-prime-counting-function-are-equal/1684989#1684989) may help too. Fine continuation,

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your implementation of $\mathrm{R}(x)$.  You can't use a 1-argument $\mathrm{li}(x)$ here due to its branch cut, which prevents it from properly inverting $x^{\rho/n}$.

Apply $\mathrm{li}(x^y) = \mathrm{li}(e^{y \ln x}) = \mathrm{Ei}(y \ln x)$ to obtain

$$ \mathrm{R}(x^\rho) = \mathrm{R}(x, \rho) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \mathrm{Ei}(\frac{\rho}{n} \ln(x)) $$

Removing $\rho$ from the exponent has eschewed crossing the branch cut.  This form gave great convergence over your graphs' domains with 20 paired zeros and a summation to $n<\sqrt x$.

Comment: But this formula is dependent on Möbius function, which requires factorization of all numbers up to $n$. So we are moving inside a loop - tell me factorizations of all numbers then I tell you how much primes there is. But if I already knew factorizations I do not need some complicated formula to count primes because I already knew them. I hoped for a formula that uses definition:
${\displaystyle \operatorname {R} (x)=1+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(\ln x)^{k}}{k!k\zeta (k+1)}}}$
which is totally independent from knowing primes.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because whatever you're using inteprets the logarithm in the definition of the R function as the principal branch of log (x^rho) when it should instead be rho times log (x) 
I don't know a program that implements the R function like that so you must work each term out by yourself: replace the RiemannR (x^rho) with (1+ sum k=1...inf (rho*log (x))^k!/k/zeta (k+1) )
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2004630

Comment: Please use MathJax to provide mathematical equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The best advice is to forget about $\pi(x)$ and look instead at $\psi(x) = x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\ln 2\pi - \frac12 \ln(1-x^{-2})$

Comment: @Just Some Nerdy Teen It does not work even if I replace $\ln(x^{\rho})$ with $\rho \ln(x)$.

Comment: @reuns OK, I looked at that instead and think I understand that part. Now can we return to $\pi(x)$? This part I still do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Also it should actually be RiemannR (x)+arctan (pi/log(x))/pi-1/log(x)-sum k=1...inf (RiemannR (x^rho(k))+RiemannR (x^rho (-k))) where rho denotes ONLY the nontrivial zeros and the last summands again need to be interpreted as what I just said.

Source: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2004630 (you can read it for free online ;3)

Comment: It does not work even if I replace $\ln(x^{\rho})$ with $\rho \ln(x)$

Comment: No, those are equivalent.  The summation over the trivial zeros is equivalent to the $-1/\ln{x} + 1/\pi \arctan{\pi / \ln{x}}$ term.  @azerbajdzan's problem is his evaluation of the Riemann R function.  You cannot use any 1-argument form here due to the branch cut.