# Riemann explicit formula for $\pi(x)$ and its evaluation

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

We have for $x>1$:

> $$\tag{1}\pi^*(x)=R(x)-\sum_{\rho} R(x^{\rho})$$

$\rho$-s are zeros of Riemann zeta function (trivial and nontrivial).
I know how to derive $(1)$ and also know how to derive:
$$\tag{2}\psi^*(x)=x-\sum_{\rho} \frac {x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}$$
**This question concerns only about $(1)$ so please do not answer like "instead of $(1)$ look at $(2)$".** (I know it is somehow easier in understanding and evaluation.)

Back to $(1)$...

$R(x)$ is Rieamann R-function and is defined as:

$$\tag{3}R(x)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\big(\log(x)\big)^n}{nn! \zeta (n+1)}$$
Now, whether I use $$\tag{3.1}R(x^\rho)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\big(\log(x^\rho)\big)^n}{nn! \zeta (n+1)}$$ or $$\tag{3.2}R(x^\rho)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\big(\rho \log(x)\big)^n}{nn! \zeta (n+1)}$$ in $(1)$, in both cases I do not get $\pi^*(x)$. (Series seems to diverge/oscillate.)

**Can you tell me what a definition of $R(x)$ to use to get the correct results?**
**I am interested only in exact formulas, approximations are out of interest!**

I have seen approximations using Möbius function $\mu(x)$ and exponential integral $Ei\big(\rho \log(x)\big)$.

Comment: @reuns How does this help me to evaluate $(1)$?

Comment: A typo. $\text{Li}(x)$ appears from $\Pi(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{1}{k} = \int_{2-\epsilon}^x \frac{\psi'(y)}{\log y}dy$. Then $R(x)$ appears from $\pi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \Pi(x^{1/n})$.

Comment: I've been looking long and hard for a good reference for this, but it seems oddly under-researched in the literature... :-(

Comment: @Markus Shepherd As far as I know the expression $(1)$ has not yet been proved by anybody. And also I have not seen anywhere, that somebody used it for evaluation of $\pi(x)$, they always use a different/modified formula, that is just an approximation. The formula uses Moebius function and exponential integral. So $(1)$  is to me just hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

There is the easiest way to obtain convergent explicit formulas :

Since $$\psi(x) =\sum_{p^k \le x} \log p=( x-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi)1_{x > 2}$$ (sum over trivial and non-trivial zeros)

Letting $\Pi(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{1}{k}= \int_{2-\epsilon}^x \frac{\psi'(x)}{\log x}dx$ and $1_{x > 2}\int_2^x ( \frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^\rho}{\rho}) \frac{dx}{\log x} = 1_{x > 2}\int_2^x \frac{\rho t^{\rho-1}}{\rho\log t} dt=1_{x > 2}\int_{2^\rho}^{x^\rho} \frac{u}{\log u} du= (\text{li}(x^\rho)-\text{li}(2^\rho))1_{x > 2}$

then $$\Pi(x) = (\text{li}(x)-\text{li}(2))1_{x > 2}-\sum_\rho (\text{li}(x^\rho)-\text{li}(2^\rho))1_{x > 2}$$

Now let $\pi(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \Pi(x^{1/n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \Pi(x^{1/n})1_{x^{1/n}> 2}$ and $\text{R}_\rho(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} (\text{li}(x^{\rho/n})-\text{li}(2^{\rho/n}))1_{x^{1/n} > 2}$ (those are finite sums)

therefore
$$\pi(x) = \text{R}_1(x)-\sum_\rho \text{R}_\rho(x)$$

Comment: It does not work even with your definition of $R_\rho(x)$.

Comment: I agree that it is finite, but the result of such computation is not $\pi(x)$.

Comment: @azerbajdzan What do you mean ? Of course it is, by definition.

Comment: there was a typo I meant $1_{x^{1/n}>2}$

Comment: Can you tell me what software do you use? I used Mathematica for computation. Maybe your software use a different definition of $\text{li}(x)$ for complex arguments. But if we stick to standard definition like I think Mathematica (or SAGE) do then the formula does not hold. The phase of $x^{\rho}$ is important, but that information is lost when evaluating in  $\text{li}(x^{\rho})$.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I meant $1_{x > 2}\int_2^x ( \frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^\rho}{\rho}) \frac{dx}{\log x} = 1_{x > 2}\int_2^x \frac{\rho t^{\rho-1}}{\rho\log t} dt=1_{x > 2}\int_{2^\rho}^{x^\rho} \frac{u}{\log u} du= (\text{li}(x^\rho)-\text{li}(2^\rho))1_{x > 2}$  and it is analytic in $\rho,\Re(\rho) > 0$ and positive for $\rho > 0$

Comment: Can you tell me what is numeric value of $(\text{li}(x^\rho)-\text{li}(2^\rho))1_{x > 2}$ for $x=4$ and $\rho=1/2 +14.1347i$? I got $0.969625+5.39972 i$

Comment: @azerbajdzan Right it seems there is a problem with the branch implemented by mathematica http://urlz.fr/69fY

Comment: But that is a standard way of implementing it, I think all math softwares do it this way.

Comment: @azerbajdzan You need to modify it such that the plot is continuous on $t \in (0,1)$, ie. such that $li(x^\rho)$ is analytic on $\Re(\rho) > 0$, possibly just by multiplying by $-1$ for $|x^\rho| < ...$. Try plotting $\Pi(x) - li(x)$ to understand what you need to plot.

Comment: This is the point of this thread, that nobody seems to provide an appropriate definition of $R(x)$ or $li(x)$ as infinite series that would be suitable to evaluate the $(1)$ of the original question.

Comment: Here the definition is $1_{x > 2}\int_2^x ( \frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^\rho}{\rho}) \frac{dt}{\ln t}$ with $t^\rho = e^{\rho \ln(t)}$, there is no ambiguity about it. Also you don't have so many good reasons to not say $\Pi(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \frac{\psi(n+1/2)-\psi(n-1/2)}{\ln n}, \pi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\Pi(x^{1/n})$ is not an explicit formula for $\pi(x)$.

Comment: I have not. Just maybe it is not as elegant as $(1)$ if all we would need to evaluate it was Gram series in $(3)$ and zeros of $\zeta(s)$. But seems one universal definition of $R(x)$ is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed many traps while evaluating $\pi(x)$ using the $\zeta$ zeros
(I will neglect here the smooth and quickly decreasing with $x$ contribution of the trivial zeros).
This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684989/21783) detailed most of these traps but let's examine your specific points :

> Now, whether I use $$\tag{3.1}R(x^\rho)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
> \frac{\big(\log(x^\rho)\big)^n}{nn! \zeta (n+1)}$$ or
>   $$\tag{3.2}R(x^\rho)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\big(\rho
> \log(x)\big)^n}{nn! \zeta (n+1)}$$ in $(1)$, in both cases I do not
>   get $\pi^*(x)$. (Series seems to diverge/oscillate.)

The known non trivial zeros $\rho$ verify the RH and may thus be written $\,\displaystyle\rho:=\frac 12+it$.
Now $(3.1)$ can't indeed provide the right answer because the numerical evaluation of $x^\rho$, before applying the logarithm, will give you for $x$ real $>1\quad\displaystyle x^\rho=\exp\left(\left(\frac 12+it\right)\log(x)\right)$.
The problem is that the evaluation of the logarithm will not return $\,\left(\frac 12+it\right)\log(x)\;$ but something like $\left(\frac 12+it\right)\log(x)+2\pi ki\;$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ depending of $t$ (the evaluation of the logarithm imposing a phase in $(-\pi,\pi]\;$)

Using a different phase reference (branch) for the terms of the series isn't a fine idea but what about the Gram series as used in $(3.2)$?
This formula is indeed correct and was the one I used to produce this [animation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009419/21783) for $x\in(1,100)$. But this formula too has to be handled with care because we have to evaluate something behaving like (since $\,\zeta(n)\sim 1\,$ as $\,n\to +\infty$) :$$S(z):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{nn!},\quad z:=\left(\frac 12+it\right)\log(x)$$
For the first non trivial zero and (say) $\,x=100\,$ we gave $|z|>65$, for the tenth $|z|>229$, for the hundredth  $|z|>1089$.
The problem is that the terms of $S(z)$ and thus $R(x^\rho)\,$ will become very large (about $\dfrac {e^z}{z\sqrt{2 \pi z}}$ near $n=z$) before decreasing again to get under unity after about $\,\lceil e\,z\rceil\,$ terms. In practice for $\,x=100\,$ and the $100$-th non trivial zero you will need a working precision of $480$ digits!

---

Another idea proposed by reuns is to use the [Möbius $\mu$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) formula (no high precision here) :

$$\tag{1}R(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil\log_2(x)\rceil}  \frac{\mu(n)}n \operatorname{li}\bigl(x^{1/n}\bigr)$$
(since $\ \displaystyle\pi^{*}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}n \Pi^*\bigl(x^{1/n}\bigr)\;$ with $\Pi^*(z)=0\;$ for $\,z<2\;$ we need only the $\,\lceil\log_2(x)\rceil\;$ first terms for all the $R(x^\rho)$ expressions ... not just $R(x)$)

But from the [logarithm in the $\operatorname{li}$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Integral_representation) we get exactly the same problem of "phase reduction" as previously. Fortunately a simply remedy exists from the definition of the [exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Relation_with_other_functions) by using $\,\operatorname{li}\left(e^x\right)=\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ and replacing $(1)$ with :
$$\tag{2}R(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil\log_2(x)\rceil} \frac{\mu(n)}n \operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac 1n\log(x)\right)$$
and 
$$\tag{3}R\left(x^\rho\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil\log_2(x)\rceil}  \frac{\mu(n)}n \operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac {\rho}n\log(x)\right)$$

The result for $\;\pi(x),\;x\in(2,100)$ (starting with $R(x)$ evaluated using the Gram series, subtracting the exact $\;\displaystyle\frac 1{\log(x)}-\frac 1{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{\log(x)}\right)\;$ contribution for the trivial zeros and two times the real part of the sum of the $\,200\,$ first non trivial zeros $\,R\left(x^\rho\right)\,$ terms using $(3)\;$) should be :
[image: pi(x)]

Concerning the use of the $\zeta$ zeros to evaluate the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ as in your expression $(1)$ this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009419/21783) may he helpful.
Shortly the combinatorial Meissel-Lehmer method allowed to compute $\pi(x)$ up to $10^{23}$ while the analytic method allowed to go up to $10^{25}$ (in $2016$, I don't know the state of the art). Note that more efficient expressions than $(1)$ were used as you may find in the   [history by Büthe](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/jbuethe/topics/AnalyticPiX.html) and references.

Comment: The problem with formulas involving Möbius μ function is that the plotted graph does not look nice, it is not smooth (like are mine two submitted graphs of $\psi^*(x)$ and $\Pi^*(x)$). And it also seems there is some other problem with your graph - for $2<x<3$ it is a way out of correct values.

Comment: Also your animation has some problems. For example for $13<x<17$ the approximation with 100 zeros is worse than with n=20.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: the problem in the $(2,3)$ interval was corrected by replacing the $R(x)$ Moebius sum I used by the (exact) Gram series. Concerning your other remarks : Well, we get what we get ! (I created my animation around year $2000$ and reverified the picture for $n=100$ it appears right : the Gram series seem to produce  these "wide scale waves". I still don't know a convergence proof for your $(1)$ using Gram or Möbius sums but  D. Platt studied the convergence of his sums without supposing R.H. in my second link). Excellent and nicer animations,

Answer (score 0):

$$\psi^*(x) =\sum_{p^k \le x} \log p$$
[image]

$$\Pi^*(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{1}{k}$$
[image]