# Gram series in Riemann explicit formula for π(x)

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Based on Raymond Manzoni's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2822928 we know that Gram series in sum over non-trivial zeros of zeta-function has a slow converging because of large x. And we know that general converging series for Ei[1] (exponential integral) looks very similar to Gram series (except the zeta function term in the denominator in Gram series) and has the same problem for large x as the Gram series. But it exists a very rapidly converging continued fractions for Ei[1] (for large x):
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/expint/expint_n.html#math_toolkit.expint.expint_n.implementation

Maybe there is a way to find similar continued fractions for Gram series?

Comment: If you have the hope that, say , $\pi(10^{300})$ can be determined exactly with such an approach, I must disappoint you. $li(x)$ is already an excellent approximation and I do not think we can improve this significantly without a lot of effort.

Comment: No, I'm about x<10^9 where Gram series is better

Comment: In this range , of course.